# How do I export a handlebars file and how do i import it in a JS file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, handlebars.js, templating

This whole time i have have been learning `handlebars/backbone/marionette` and have been writing everything inline in one file, so there was no need for export/import.

But if i am making a file specifically for handle bars how do i go about exporting it (not talking about using it in script tags, i am talking about es6 exports) and how do i import the file in a JS file so that i can use the template.

lets say I have a .hbs file like this

```
<div id="listItem-container">
    <h1>List Item Container</h1>
</div>
```

how do i import it in a js file like this

```
import ListView from '../../template/listView';
```

Comment: I don't think it's achievable in plain ES6 (stick to the import syntax). Did you use something like webpack? With proper loader configuration, it may be feasible.

Comment: yes I am using webpack, is it something that webpack handles?

Comment: Something like handlebars-loader do exist,but I'm not sure if it fits your need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can import hbs files directly, but you can use node's File System package to do it.
You can do something like this

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const listView = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `../../template/listView`), 'utf8');
```

Of course you would also need to import the handlebars package and transform the template with the data, otherwise you will end up with stuff like {{var}} in your output.